# Block access to all php files in subdirectory

Tags: apache-2.2, apache-2.4, .htaccess, apache2

I need to block access to all .php files in a subdirectory of my web root. I know that I could create a .htaccess in this subdirectory and use the following:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(?i:php)$">
<IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
Order allow,deny
Deny from all
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
Require all denied
</IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
```

However, for the sake of transparency / simplicity I really need to do the blocking from the web root .htaccess and NOT via one in the subdirectory.

If I were to block a specific file from the root .htaccess I would use this:

```
<Location /wp-includes/somefile.php>
<IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
Order allow,deny
Deny from all
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
Require all denied
</IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
```

I've read that you can't use LocationMatches in the .htaccess, so is there another way that I can do this (without creating a .htaccess for the sub-directory?

***UPDATE***
It appears that `<Location>` can't be used in .htaccess either.

Answer (score 3):

The `<Location>` (and `<LocationMatch>`) directives match against the URL-path, not strictly the filesystem path, so it's not necessarily recommended to use this to control access anyway (in the server config).

If you have access to the server config then you would just use the relevant `<Directory>` container.

Without using a `.htaccess` in the subdirectory you could use mod_setenvif to set an environment variable conditionally based on the requested URL and then block based on this env var.

For example:

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI "^/subdirectory/.+\.php$" BLOCK

<IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
  Order deny,allow
  Deny from env=BLOCK
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
  <RequireAll>
    Require all granted
    Require not env BLOCK
  </RequireAll>
</IfModule>
```

I reversed the `Order` directive (Apache 2.2), otherwise, without an additional `Allow` directive, everything would be blocked.

The Apache 2.4 directives need to be inside a `<RequireAll>` container, first granting all access (otherwise *everything* is blocked) and then denying access conditionally when the `BLOCK` env var is set. You can't have a negated `Require` directive - in an implied `<RequireAny>` container - as it won't have any effect (in fact, this results in a 500 error).

Note that this blocks URLs, not strictly "files". It blocks requests that look like `.php` files in `/subdirectory` - regardless of whether they actually exist as physical files.

---

Alternatively, you could use mod_rewrite (Apache 2.2 and 2.4) at the top of your root `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^subdirectory/.+\.php$ - [F]
```

This simply blocks (403 Forbidden) all URLs that end in `.php` that are in the requested `/subdirectory`. If you specifically need to only return a 403 for URLs that map to real files then you can include an additional condition (although this is probably unnecessarily wasteful):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^subdirectory/.+\.php$ - [F]
```

Change `F` to `R=404` if you wanted to return a 404 instead.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed info, it's appreciated. I'll take a proper look asap.